# How to write PDF to HttpResponseMessage using iText 7

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext7

I'm trying to generate a PDF and write it to HTTP response using iText 7 and iText7.pdfHtml libraries.

The HTML content for the PDF is stored in a `StringBuilder` object.

Not sure what the correct process of doing this is because as soon as I use `HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf`, the `MemoryStream` is closed and I cannot access the bytes. I get the following exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.

```
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
StringBuilder htmlText = new StringBuilder();
htmlText.Append("<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>");
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(memoryStream))
    {
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

        string headerText = "my header";
        string footerText = "my footer";

        pdfDocument.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new HeaderFooterEventHandler(document, headerText, footerText));

        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlText.ToString(), pdfWriter);

        memoryStream.Flush();
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
        memoryStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);

        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/pdf");
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "sample.pdf"
        };
        httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }//end using pdfwriter
}//end using memory stream
```

**EDIT**
Added `PdfDocument` and `Document` objects to manipulate header/footer and new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the fact that you have a `MemoryStream` and replace

```
    memoryStream.Flush();
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
    memoryStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
```

by

```
byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

That method is documented to also work with closed memory streams.

Comment: `memoryStream.ToArray()` worked perfectly and the action returned a nice looking PDF. But when I added `PdfDocument` and `Document` objects to manipulate header/footer, I'm getting a bad PDF. The PDF returned cannot be opened by reader due to corrupted file.

Comment: I don't see your code closing the `PdfDocument`. Thus, the result is unfinished. Close it after `ConvertToPdf`.

Comment: This is what I get after adding `PdfDocument.Close()`: `iText.Kernel.PdfException: Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.`

Comment: For some reason this worked `HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(htmlText.ToString(), pdfDocument, new ConverterProperties());` instead of `HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlText.ToString(), pdfWriter);`

Comment: Ok. I assume the overload with the pdf writer internally creates its own`PdfDocument`, and two `PdfDocument` instances working on the same writer may cause problems.